# How to unit test go code that interacts with Elasticsearch

Tags: unit-testing, go, testing, mocking

I have an application that defines a `type Client struct {}` which talks to various other clients in my code that talk to services like github, elasticsearch etc.

Now I have the following ES code in one of my packages

```
type SinkService interface {
    Write(context, index, mapping, doc)
}

type ESSink struct {
   client *elastic.Client
}

func NewESSink() *ESSink {}

 // checks if the index exists and writes the doc
func (s *ESSink) Write(context, index, mapping, doc) {}
```

I use this method in my main client that runs the whole application like this `c.es.Write(...)`. Now if I want to write `client_test.go` I can simply make a mockESSink and use it with some stub code but that won't cover the lines written in my ES code.

How do I unit test my ES code? My ESSink uses an `elastic.Client`. How do I mock that?

I would like to embed some mock ES client that gives me stub responses and I will be able to test my `ESSink.Write` method that way.

Comment: Same way you mock anything, you'd have to replace the `elastic.Client` field with an interface that defines the methods you use, and then create a mock that satisfies the interface for use in your tests.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on your question, I assume you're using [`github.com/olivere/elastic`](https://github.com/olivere/elastic), and you want to be able to test by using stub http responses. When I first read this question, I also have never written Go test code that use ES client. So, in addition to answering this question, I'm also sharing how I find out the answer from the godocs.

First, we can see that [`elastic.NewClient`](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/olivere/elastic/v7@v7.0.14?tab=doc#NewClient) accepts client option functions. So I checked what kind of client option functions the library provides. Turns out the library provides [`elastic.SetHttpClient`](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/olivere/elastic/v7@v7.0.14?tab=doc#SetHttpClient) that accepts [`elastic.Doer`](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/olivere/elastic/v7@v7.0.14?tab=doc#Doer). The `Doer` is an interface that `http.Client` can implement. From here, the answer becomes clear.

So, you have to:

1. Change your `func NewESSink()` to accept http Client or elastic Client.
2. Write stub http Client (implements `elastic.Doer`).

**ESSink**

```golang
type ESSink struct {
    client *elastic.Client
}

func NewESSink(client *elastic.Client) *ESSink {
    return &ESSink{client: client}
}
```

**Stub HttpClient**

```golang
package stubs

import "net/http"

type HTTPClient struct {
    Response *http.Response
    Error    error
}

func (c *HTTPClient) Do(*http.Request) (*http.Response, error) {
    return c.Response, c.Error
}
```

**Your testing code**

```golang
func TestWrite(t *testing.T) {
    // set the body and error according to your test case
    stubHttpClient := stubs.HTTPClient{ 
        Response: &http.Response{Body: ...},
        Error: ...,
    }

    elasticClient := elastic.NewClient(elastic.SetHttpClient(stubHttpClient))
    esSink := NewESSink(elasticClient)
    esSink.Write(...)
}
```

In your production code, you can use `http.Client{}` when setting ES http client.

Comment: I never even bothered to take a look at the options, was thinking about dropping the idea of testing this altogether, thanks so much @erick-wijaya